# issue when I run ffmpeg

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, opencv3.0

ffmpeg was working fine until I got the following error message.

> ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.2.4:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried to install opencv again 
I followed this [script](https://github.com/milq/milq/blob/master/scripts/bash/install-opencv.sh)

```
$ opencv_version 
3.4.1
```

any idea

Thks

Comment: I got a solution :

I just delete all instance of opencv and ffmpeg, uninstall ffmpeg, and then install it again, now work fine :) 

    sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -R {} \; 
    sudo find / -name "*ffmpeg*" -exec rm -R {} \;
    sudo apt-get install ffmpeg

Comment: you shouldn't answer in comments, post this as a solution below and then you can accept your answer after 48 hours for everyone else who has this issue int he future.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed Opencv 3.4.1 & are trying to use 2.4, emphasis mine:

> ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.**2.4**: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Update your FFMPEG library and all should be groovy